# Deep labeling of parameters inside pegjs regex group

Tags: javascript, pegjs

Consider the following grammar:

```
list
 = head:item (',' tail:item)*
 { return [head].concat(tail); }

item
 = $ ([0-9]*)
```

It should describe lists of positive integers.

The problem is that `tail` is undefined as it is inside parens.

So I'm forced to do the following:

```
list
 = head:item tail:tail*
 { return [head].concat(tail); }

tail
 = ',' item:item
 { return item; }

item
 = $ ([0-9]*)
```

This can be quite cumbersome in longer grammars.

Is there any way to label what's inside the `(',' item)` regex group?

Comment: I think that's how it's supposed to work. It's cumbersome but it helps the grammar optimize since the "tail" rule can be cached between calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed label what's inside the group (`i:` below), tell PEGJS exactly what to return (`{return i;}`), and label the result as well (`tail:`).

```
list
 = head:item tail:(',' i:item {return i;})*
 { return [head].concat(tail); }
```